# How to define a string in Scheme - any string that I choose?

Tags: string, syntax, scheme

Given that:

```
(define output "")
```

or that

```
(define output "goodInput")
```

When I run those defines in my code, I get:

```
ERROR: In procedure memoization:
ERROR: Bad define placement (define output "").
```

Why is that ?

**EDIT:**

```
; Formal function of the code
(define (double->sum myString)

(define myVector 0)
(set! myVector (breaking myString))
(define output "")
(define returnValue  (checkLegit myVector)) ; check the number of legitimate characters ,they need to be either numbers or "."
(define flag 0)   
(if (not(= returnValue (vector-length myVector))) (set! output "Input error") (set! flag (+ flag 1)))

(define i 0)            ; the length of the vector
(define count 0)        ; the value of all the numbers in the vector

(if 
    (= flag 1)

(do ()                             
  ((= i (vector-length myVector))) ; run until the end of the vector
  (cond 
    ((char=? (vector-ref myVector i) #\.) ; check if we found a dot 
               (set! output (appending output count))    (set! output (appendingStrings output ".")) (set! count 0)
    )

    (else (set! count (+ count (char->integer(vector-ref myVector i))    ))  (set! count (- count 48))
    ); end of else

  ) ; end of cond

  (set! i (+ i 1))    ; inc "i" by 1
); end of do
) ; end do 

; if flag = 1 , then the input is in a correct form
(if (= flag 1) (set! output (appending output count)))

(if (= flag 1)
    output
    "Input error")
) ; END
```

Comment: Is there any line of code before the line you posted? Can you add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the string definition itself (there are no strange characters, or anything like that), it's in the *place* within the code where that definition is happening: you're inside a procedure, and the last line in a procedure can not be a `define`. Try returning something after the definition and it should work fine.

I guess that you've just started writing the procedure, just keep going after the `define` and write the rest of the code. For the time being, use a placeholder value at the end, so the interpreter won't complain:

```
(define (double->sum myString)
  (define myVector 0) 
  (set! myVector (breaking myString))
  (define output "")
  'ok)
```

Also a matter of style - although it's ok to define-and-set a variable like that, it's more idiomatic to use a `let` expression for defining local variables. This is what I mean:

```
(define (double->sum myString)
  (let ((myVector (breaking myString))
        (output ""))
    'ok))
```

In that way, you won't have to use `set!`, which mutates the variable and goes against the functional-programming style preferred in Scheme.

Comment: Oscar , I have a lot more code below ... see the edited post .

Comment: @ron that doesn't change my answer, the problem remains the same - the `define` can not be the last line in the procedure. Also make sure that your parenthesis are fine, it might be as simple as that.

Comment: No ,the last line of the code is not define . Please see the entire code above , edited

Comment: @ron the code compiles fine, I don't get the error you're reporting. The only thing I had to change was replacing a couple of `if` for `when`, because they didn't have a corresponding `else` clause (that's an error for Racket, but I believe your interpreter doesn't complain for that)

Comment: @ron It'd help a lot if you indented the code properly, it's very hard to read. And please stop treating closing parenthesis as if they were braces, do not put them in a separate line, leave them in the same line. You keep trying to program in Scheme as if it were a C-like language, that's the core of the problem

Comment: @ÓscarLópez In standard Scheme, internal definitions can only appear at the _start_ of a procedure (and not just "not at the end"). Special exception: for Scheme implementations (like Guile) that use docstrings, the docstring appears before internal definitions.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: It turned out that I had to move all the `define` outside the function declaration , i.e. make them globals. Without that ,nothing worked . Thanks for your help .

Comment: @ron as @ChrisJester-Young points out, the problem was caused because in your Scheme implementation all the defines must come first, in your code there's a `set!` in-between two defines at the beginning, so that was the problem. It's not a good idea to declare the defines as globals if they're referring to values local to only one procedure. Notice that by using `let` in the way I suggested in my solution, none of this would have happened.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: You're right , from now on I'll use `let` , much appreciated .